# Rails 3 and Bundler. How to deploy and NOT package gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

I'm having lots of problems trying to deploy using capistrano. I keep on getting errors about libv8 not in any of the sources.

```
Could not find libv8-3.11.8.13 in any of the sources
```

Here https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/56 tells you that you could "not to use packaging", that way, the deployed app won't use the bundle package.

How can I deploy and use the gems **NOT IN THE BUNDLE PACKAGE**? I want the app do run bundle everytime I deploy instead or to just run bundle when the Gemfile has changed.

Comment: can you show some stack trace? have you installed `libv8-dev` library? and `libv8` gem?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working: https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/77#issuecomment-12711634

I'm doing development on a mac and deploying to a red hat server. It seems Rails needs a OS, platform-specific version of the gem. So when I'm running bundle on my development machine (mac) and then deploy it with capistrano to the production server (red hat), it won't work.

What I ended up doing is...

- manually download the libv8 gem I needed from http://rubygems.org/gems/libv8
- copy the downloaded gem to the vendor/cache folder
- then deployed the app (cap deploy:cold)

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you're missing the bundle capistrano task. See https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb for more. You should be able to "require 'bundler/capistrano'" to your capistrano deploy.rb file so that bundle is run on every deploy.